# LINQPad crashes with "OutOfMemoryException" on startup?

Tags: .net-4.0, linqpad

I have Linqpad in Windows7 64 bit. It was working fine till last week, but suddenly it started crashing while starting the program itself. The following are the event logs

**.NET Runtime**

```
Application: LINQPad.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at LINQPad.Program.ProcessException(System.Exception)
   at LINQPad.Program.Start(System.String[])
   at LINQPad.ProgramStarter.Run(System.String[])
   at LINQPad.Loader.Main(System.String[])
```

**Application Error**

```
Faulting application name: LINQPad.exe, version: 4.31.0.0, time stamp: 0x4cfb29be
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e211319
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x1c68
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccc4506f8b6553
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\LINQPad4\LINQPad.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: af0a8ac8-3043-11e1-9f3c-f0def166a9e4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Comment: I started getting this after updating to the latest version.  If you try running it a few times, you might get lucky and it won't crash.